# SharePoint 2013 - Gantt chart - time line - slow

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, performance, task-list, timeline

We have a SharePoint task list that displays a Timeline to the users. In my production system it takes about 22-25 seconds to load, UAT 10 seconds.

Some notes:

- The time line colour coded based on a naming convention
- 200 sub sites in the site collection
- Each sub site has one task list
- Each list has approx 100 tasks in it
- There is no change in load time if I un tick the timeline in the web part
- SQL server usage looks ok
- App server - Noderunner takes 10gb of 12gb of ram........????
- We don't see any spikes on any of the servers when the lists are loading.

is this just load causing the issue, where do I start my tuning, Where do I start my trouble shooting and how?

any help would be much appreciated.